# stats::lm() in R: getting number of observations for factor level

Tags: r, lm

Consider the following linear model in R:

```
> stats::lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data=iris)
Call:
stats::lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)  Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
            3.428             -0.658             -0.454
```

Is there a **general** way to get the number of observations *per factor level*? (if I can not rely on the input to be a nicely formatted `data.frame` as `iris` is, and I do not know the name of the field in advance)

This could be something like `nobs()`, but for the subset where `iris$Species == "versicolor"`.

Comment: `table(model.frame(fit)$Species)` should give you what you need.  The key being the `model.frame` function extracts the data frame used to fit the model (after taking the specified `na.action`).

Comment: @Benjamin You should make this a full answer.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it! If yo add it as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: @Roland, I'd love to, but it didn't really satisfy the requirements he provided.  Specifically, he wanted something he could use without knowing the name of the field in advance.  I'm not quite sure what that solution would look like, but `model.frame` would be the place I would start.

Comment: well...in that case.... :)

Comment: For not knowing the names, just iterating over the `colnames` of `model.frame` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the comments above indicate a willingness to accept this as an answer:

```
table(model.frame(fit)$Species)
```

Provides a table of the results, but it isn't in data.frame format, but can certainly be managed.

Comment: I think you can handle the situation where the variable name is not known by `table(model.frame(fit)[names(fit$xlevels)])` or `sapply(names(fit$xlevels), function(a) table(model.frame(fit)[a]))`